# How can I find all rectangles adjacent to particular rectangle on a given list of rectangles?

Tags: python, algorithm, computational-geometry

Given a rectangle R1 and a list of of rectangles R2,R3,.... 
How can I find all rectangles that are connected with the main rectangle R1.

I don't just need the rectangle that are directly connected to R1 but also all that are indirectly connected to R1.
For Example if R2 is connected to R1 and R3 is connected to R2. R3 is considered connected to R1.

Rectangles are given in the form (xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax).
All rectangles are parallel to the axis.
Rectangles are considered connected when they are either overlapping or touching. 
When they just touch in the corner they are not considered connected.

Example:

```
____________
_111________
_11122______
____22______
____22______
____333333__ 
____22______
__55___4444_
__55___4444_
```

In this example R1,R2,R3 are connected with each other. So I need to return R1,R2,R3.

R4, and R5 are not connected.

An obvious solution would be to compare each each rectangle with eachother O(n^2).
But I think there should be faster solutions.
I have tried to use Implement a sweep line algorithm with an Interval Tree. But it is to slow.
I need a solution in O(n log n)

Comment: is that continuous space or discrete space?

Comment: Please show your attempts to fix the problem, and where you encountered problems. Check [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (mcve)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Are you referring to n as points or as rectangles?

Answer (score 0):

Make 2 lists, one containing X-coordinate objects and one containing Y-containing objects.

The object will consist of (the coordinate, the rectangle number and whether the coordinate corresponds to min or max).

Sort both lists O(nlogn) and traverse any one. On encountering a min-coordinate add the rectangle in a stack, on encountering a max-coordinate remove the rectangle. If multiple rectangles are added together in a stack, add them in a group, while removing a rectangle the group will correspond to all the overlapping rectangles. Store the information of such groups. Do the same procedure using the other list. The common rectangles in groups obtained from both X and Y lists will be the overlapping rectangles.

The solution is O(nlogn).

Comment: But if do this I will only find overlapping rectangles. I also need the touching ones.

Comment: Before removing a rectangle check the list further to see if the coordinate is the same. If it is, remove it and add it to the current group.

Comment: I think i have not specified the format clearly. For example R1 would (1,1,3,2) R2 would be(4,2,5,6) R3=(4,5,9,5). I could just add 1 to every xmax but than R5 would be connected.

Comment: what do mean by R1 is (1,1,3,2)

Comment: The input for R1 (xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax) for the example.

Comment: Don't add 1 to every xmax. If a current xmax is equal to next consecutive xmin(s), add them in the same group. Although This will also include touching rectangles.

Comment: How do i find commen rectangles in O(n logn)?

Comment: Did you get the groups I was talking about? Are you finding problem in finding the intersections of groups?

Comment: Was i did get the groups you are talking about. I even found a solution to my problem with touching rectangles. But i fail the intersect the groups.